# display text from array in html label tags with unque id using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, innerhtml, innertext

i'm new in javascript,
i have the following html code:

```
<form role="form" >       
<label for="element1" id="element1_label"></label>
<input type="text" id="element1" />

<label for="element2" id="element2_label"></label>
<input type="text" id="element2" name="element2">

<label for="element3" id="element3_label"></label>
<input type="number" id="element3" name="element3s">

<button type="submit" >submit</button>
```

and i want to display some text from `options` array by following javascript code:

```
       var piced = 'opt';
        var options = {
            opt: {
                element1_label: "text1",
                element2_label: "text2",
                element3_label: "text3",
            },
            newopt: {
                element1_label: "new text1",
                element2_label: "new text2",
                element3_label: "new text3",
            }
        };

        jQuery('label').each(function()
        {
            jQuery(this).innerText = options[piced][jQuery(this).attr('id')];

        });
```

i want to display in each html label value of such index of piced array.
for example:

```
<label for="element1" id="element1"> text1 </label>
<input type="text" id="element1" />

<label for="element2" id="element2"> text2 </label>
<input type="text" id="element2" name="element2">
```

but this code not change the text of label tags.what is problem?

Comment: `ID` should be unique throughout the page

Comment: opps! I changed the ID still not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a vanilla Javascript approach which loops through the labels and writes the `textContent` of each label (`labels[i].textContent`) as:

```
options[piced][labels[i].id];
```

```js
var piced = 'opt';

var options = {
    
    opt: {
        element1_label: "text1",
        element2_label: "text2",
        element3_label: "text3",
    },

    newopt: {
        element1_label: "new text1",
        element2_label: "new text2",
        element3_label: "new text3",
    }

};

var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');

for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labels[i].textContent = options[piced][labels[i].id];
}
```

```html
<form role="form" >       
<label for="element1" id="element1_label"></label>
<input type="text" id="element1" />

<label for="element2" id="element2_label"></label>
<input type="text" id="element2" name="element2">

<label for="element3" id="element3_label"></label>
<input type="number" id="element3" name="element3">

<button type="submit" >submit</button>
```

---

**N.B.** I wouldn't go so far as to say *never use* `innerText` - but it **is** important to know that `textContent` is standard javascript while `innerText` is non-standard (originally a proprietary property introduced by Internet Explorer, later adopted by WebKit, Blink and Opera).

See this 2015 blog post:

- [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) (2015) by *Mozilla Developer Network*
- [The poor, misunderstood innerText](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/) (2015) by *kangax*

to fully grasp the differences between `textContent` and `innerText`.

---

The cross-browser solution (to handle legacy versions of IE) is, of course:

```
var text = element.textContent || element.innerText;
```

Comment: i dont why but in my code `var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');` return null! I use this in wordpress.

Comment: I'm not sure why either. In javascript, `document.getElementsByTagName('ELEMENT');` will always return a NodeList containing all of those ELEMENTs.

Answer (score 1):

`innerText` is a native property, not a jQuery one. The jQ equivalent is the `text()` method. Change to either:

```
 jQuery(this).text(options[piced][jQuery(this).attr('id')]);
```

or (retrieving the native element reference from the jQuery stack)

```
jQuery(this)[0].innerText = options[piced][jQuery(this).attr('id')];
```

Comment: Please don't use `$(this).attr('id')` or `$(this).prop('id')`; it's so much cheaper and easier to simply use `this.id`.

Comment: You should probably address this to the OP. I addressed his main problem; the part you reference I just copied over.

Comment: Of course, but the comment was on your answer because you copied over that portion into your working code, and there was no explanation of why it's unnecessary, and unnecessarily bad, to use jQuery to retrieve a cross-browser property of a node. Plus the OP will be - I think - notified of comments to your answer as well, plus when the answer is reviewed by the OP s/he will (presumably) also see the comment.